# Java boolean method with if statement - " must return a result of type boolean"

Tags: java, boolean

I'm having troubles with boolean methods.

```
private boolean askYesNoQuestion(String prompt){
prompt = prompt.toLowerCase();
if(prompt.equals("yes")) return true;
if(prompt.equals("no")) return false;
else prompt = readLine("Please answer yes or no.");
}
```

Eclipse says : "**the method must return a result of type boolean**".

Same problem in the following code:

```
private boolean isPerfectSquare(int n){
for(int i = 0; i <= n; i++){
if(i*i == n) {
return true;
}
else return false;
}
```

I think I already included `return` in the statements, except that they are after an `if` statement.

Comment: Please format the code a bit.

Answer (score 5):

Although you do include a pair of return statements, they all happen inside the loop. Java examines all paths, and discovers that the loop could finish without entering the very first iteration - for example, because `n` is negative. In this case the `if` statement is not going to be executed, hence there would be no `return`.

You could include an unconditional return after the loop to fix this problem. However, it looks like your logic is broken: if you enter the loop at all, you would return right away, without completing the very first iteration. It looks like you meant to write this:

```
private boolean isPerfectSquare(int n){
    for(int i = 0; i <= n; i++){
        if(i*i == n) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to return something (true or false) in the scope of the method itself as your return statements currently aren't 'visible' outside of the if statements.

You can actually omit the else statement in the second method.  For the first one, just return false outside the last else.

Answer (score 0):

Every execution path has to return a boolean. In your first example `else prompt = readLine("Please answer yes or no.");` does not return boolean

Answer (score 0):

You need to return a boolean after the for loop. The 'if' statement does not get executed if, let's say, n = -1.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, try to format your code so it's easier to follow the logic. In the first code, the reason why you're getting the error is because its possible for the method to not return anything. If prompt is not yes and its not no, it will go to the else statement. The program will run readLine, and exit the method without returning anything. What you want to do is run readline in a while loop that doesn't terminate until either yes or no is entered.

For the second problem, you have a logic problem. If n is not 0, your method will always return false. You should move put the return false line outside of the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

In your first block in else statement you haven't returned any thing.
This change will make it ok.

```
private boolean askYesNoQuestion(String prompt){
     prompt = prompt.toLowerCase();
     if(prompt.equals("yes")) 
          return true;
     if(prompt.equals("no")) 
          return false;
     else {
          prompt = readLine("Please answer yes or no.");
          return [true or false]
      }
}
```

In you second block if n be a negative value so for statement will not be running so there is no return statement in there.
And so it will be ok like this.

```
private boolean isPerfectSquare(int n){
    for(int i = 0; i <= n; i++){
        if(i*i == n) {
            return true;
        }
        else 
            return false;
    }
    return [true or false]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If a method is declared to return something, all code paths must return a value. You have two code paths that do return a value, and one that doesn't.  Formatting your code, it becomes clearer what the problem is:

```
private boolean askYesNoQuestion(String prompt) {
    prompt = prompt.toLowerCase();
    if (prompt.equals("yes")) {
        return true;
    }

    if (prompt.equals("no")) {
        return false;
    } else {
        prompt = readLine("Please answer yes or no.");
    }

    // You must return a boolean value here
}
```

Your final `else` statement is redundant - no further code will be executed if `prompt` does equal `no`. You can eliminate it and add another `return false` in the appropriate place:

```
private boolean askYesNoQuestion(String prompt) {
    prompt = prompt.toLowerCase();
    if (prompt.equals("yes")) {
        return true;
    }

    if (prompt.equals("no")) {
        return false;
    }

    writeLine("Please answer yes or no.");
    return false;
}
```

This can be further simplified. Code formatting can be very important as a first step in eliminating bugs. Reformat your second example and see if you can figure out what's required and what isn't.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all of you. It seems that the "return" statement has to be outside any loop (such as for, or while). The following code produced good results.

```
public class Test1 extends ConsoleProgram {

public void run() { 
    String prompt = readLine("Would you like instructions?");
    prompt = prompt.toLowerCase();
    while(!prompt.equals("yes") && !prompt.equals("no")){
        prompt = readLine("Please answer yes or no.");  
        prompt = prompt.toLowerCase();
    }   
    if(askYesNoQuestion(prompt)) println("Here are the instructions.");
    else println("Please start the test.");
    println(askYesNoQuestion(prompt));

}
private boolean askYesNoQuestion(String prompt){        
    if(prompt.equals("yes")) {
        return true;
    }
    else return false;              
}
```

}

The second program also works if "return" statement is outside the loop:

```
private boolean isPerfectSquare(int n){
        int i = 0;
        while (i*i != n ) {
                if (i*i > n) break; 
                i ++;
        }
        return (i*i == n);
    }
```